# training GAN_How to use Local gpu on Google Colab?

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, google-colaboratory, stylegan

Hello ，I have a problem when I am using Google Colab.
I tried to use my Local GPU on Colab,and I had been connected to Google Colab with my Jupyter,
but when I tried to execute the instruction :

`!python train.py --outdir=/stylegan2-ada-pytorch/training_results --data=./datasets/north_europe_datasets --gpus=1 --cfg=paper512 --mirror=1 --snap=10 --metrics=none`

it didn't work. On the other word，it worked，but don't produce anything in training_results file.
Please tell me how to fix it , I appreciate that,thank you!

Following are my environment which is needed by my GAN.
python 3.8.10
torch 1.7.1

image is my folders[image]

It should be some result in training_results files,not empty.

I exectuted the instruction
`!python train.py --outdir=/stylegan2-ada-pytorch/training_results --data=./datasets/north_europe_datasets --gpus=1 --cfg=paper512 --mirror=1 --snap=10 --metrics=none`

on Google Colab Gpu it worked , but when I tried to use my local GPU by connected jupyter notebook it didn't work(it shows connect successful).

by the way,I also tried to use my visual studio code to do that ,but it didn't work as well  and I even don't know why it didn't work .
I use python 3.8.10 64bit interpreter and also install  torch 1.7.1 ,
but when I execute the instruction
`python train.py --outdir=./training_results --data=./datasets/north_europe_datasets`

it still not working , and this is the img .[image]
thank you guys.